# Getting a 403 error when using Youtube API V3

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, http-status-code-403

We have a website that use Youtube API V3 in order to display youtube video. We haven't used that website for a while and somehow all of the sudden, we're getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
        "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 1234567890 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=1234567890 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
        "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=1234567890"
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 1234567890 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=1234567890 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
  }
}
```

So looking on similar error on the web, we found plenty but none of the solution worked for us. Here is what we did so far:

- Regenerate a key (didn't work)
- Remove all kinds of restrictions and allow everything `*` (didn't work)
- Erase previous API key and create a new one without any restriction (not working either)

Looking at the dashboard, we can tell that the new key is making a request to the API but somehow we keep continue getting this same error.
Now we're stuck and don't know what else to do. Any idea ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

**EDIT**
Here is how we're calling the API url (AngularJs project):

```
function getDurationFrom (videoId, callback) {
  var uri = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=' + videoId + '&part=contentDetails&key=' + YOUTUBE_API_KEY;

  $http.get(uri).then(function (response) {
    var metadata = response.data;

    if (metadata.items.length > 0) {
      var duration = metadata.items[0].contentDetails.duration;

      if (callback) {
        callback(duration);
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: your code is probably using the API key incorrectly - at a guess, since there's no code in the question - no, wait, just read the error, it seems you haven't configured something correctly

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I also updated the question with some code. As for the configuration, I don't see how this is an issue. The API is activated and we generated a new key without any restrictions. Everything is "green" on the console, but we're getting errors

Comment: `As for the configuration, I don't see how this is an issue` - well, the error states *Access Not Configured* so, that really does suggest it is the issue

Comment: One thing I'm noticing is that on the `Overview` section, it says the API is activated BUT `In order to use the API, you need to create credentials. Click here to start`....which is weird because on the `API key` section, there is a key already (the one we just recreate). Last time we used it, it was working perfectly fine, nothing has changed in our code